# Batch Script Monitoring System

Tags: file, batch-file

i need to monitor if the services have reached 80%-90%, of the capacity, it will send a warning. And I cant seem to make it work.

```
REM dir c:\|find /i "bytes free" >> CDrive.txt


 for /f %%c in (C.txt) do (


set %%c=104847433728


if %%c LSS 127578980352 (

      echo Drive is not yet full.


) elseif %%c GEQ 127578980352 (

       if %%c LSS 143526352896

           echo Send WARNING!

       if %%c LEQ 159473725441 

            echo Send CRITICAL!

)

)
```

endlocal

PAUSE

Comment: Possibly because you are using illegal statements like elseif? There is no `elseif` in batch.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing output from `dir /-c C:\ |findstr "bytes.free"` is as follows:

```
   18 Dir(s)    997019979776 bytes free
   -- ------    ------------
   ^  ^         ^ 3rd token
   ^  ^ 2nd token
   ^ 1st token
```

Then next code snippet could work, although there is something unclear for me in your logic (namely `%%c GTR 159473725441` case):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL enableextensions
for /f "tokens=3" %%c in ('dir /-c C:\ ^|findstr "bytes.free"') do (
   set "_sizeC=%%c"
   if %%c LSS 127578980352 (
      echo Drive is not yet full.
   ) else (
       if %%c LSS 143526352896 (
          echo Send WARNING!
       ) else if %%c LEQ 159473725441 echo Send CRITICAL! 
   )
)
echo _sizeC=%_sizeC%
```